# JavaScript form validation failed, values are empty, can't check them

Tags: javascript, html

Whatever I do, I can't make a working mechanism for checking if the login data is good, because the elements which should be catching passed data don't catch anything. I was debugging 
This is my form:

```
<form onsubmit= "return validate()" method="POST">
    Prvo polje:<input type="text" id='prvopolje'/>
    Drugo polje:<input type="text" id='drugopolje'/>
    Pass:<input type="password" id='passpolje'/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

And this is my password validation function:

```
function validate() {
    var polje1 = document.getElementById("prvopolje");
    var polje2 = document.getElementById("drugopolje");
    var passpolje = document.getElementById("passpolje");
    //these vars don't catch anything


    function validatepass() {
            if(passpolje.innerHTML.includes("#") ||
               passpolje.innerHTML.includes("*") ||
               passpolje.innerHTML.includes(" ") ||
               passpolje.innerHTML.includes("!") ||
               passpolje.innerHTML.includes("$") ||
               passpolje.innerHTML.includes("@") ||
               passpolje.innerHTML.includes(".") ||
               passpolje.innerHTML.includes(",") ||
               passpolje.innerHTML.includes("&") ||
               passpolje.innerHTML.includes("%") ||
               passpolje.innerHTML.includes(";"))
               {
                    console.log("Successful pass validation!");
                    return true;
               }
            else
            {

                    console.log("Not strong enough, add symbols #,*, ,!,$,@,.,,,&,%,;");
                    return false;
            }
    }
    if(polje1.innerHTML !="" ||  polje2.innerHTML!="" || validatepass())
    {
            return true;
    }
    else return false;
    }
```

What is strange, is that some data actually can be seen here in debugging mode 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzOwh.png)

Comment: `input` elements don't have `innerHTML`. Check `value` property instead.

Comment: Works great!!! Thank you!